# keep user log in after closing the application - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift5

I'm trying to keep user logged in after the application closed, i want the application remember the username/password for the user. i tried this code but it didn't work for me. Is there any alternative way? thanks

AppDelegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
  
    FirebaseApp.configure()



    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
      if user != nil {
        
        let homeController = OrderTableViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = homeController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        
    } else {
        
      let rootController = firstViewController()
      self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
      self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
    }
   }
  
    return true
       
}
```

Comment: is the app attached to a backend ?

Comment: @MohmmadS yes it is attached to the Firebase

Comment: What does the code in the question actually do? Did you verify it was executing at all? How about adding a breakpoint and inspecting both the auth and user vars and then update the question with more info about what's actually happening. e.g. is auth nil? Is user? nil? Whats's going wrong?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, but "it didn't work for me" is hard to help with. When you put a breakpoint on `if user != nil `, and run the app in a debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? What's the value of `user` at that point? What happens if you then step through the method?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase store all info about auth and user locality in phone.

try this code, it worked in my app

```
 if let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    //======
    // Load user data (profile) from firebase if needed
    //======    
    let homeController = OrderTableViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = homeController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    
} else {
    
  let rootController = firstViewController()
  self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

for use UserDefaults:

```
 if let id = UserDefaults.standard.string (forKey: "userId") as? String, id != "" {
    //======
    // Load user data (profile) from firebase if needed
    //======    
    let homeController = OrderTableViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = homeController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    
} else {
    
  let rootController = firstViewController()
  self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

Comment: did you use it in the AppDelegate or in the login viewController ?

Comment: i tried your code but it didn't work, i closed the application and i run it again but it brings the login viewController :(

Comment: please is there any alternative way to login automatically?

Comment: set breakpoint on  if let u = Auth.auth().currentUser  and check value for Auth.auth().currentUser

Comment: Be careful with `currentUser` as it could be nil because the auth object has not finished initializing. See [Auth Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). Using `addStateDidChangeListener` is generally best practice.

Comment: u can store userId to UserDefault, when signIn is success, and everytime check stored value in AppDelegate.
if value for key is exist - user is authentificated

Comment: @ВладимирКовальчук and how can i use userDefaults to store username/password , is there a tutorial? i did lot of research but i didn't find one for storing username/password.

Comment: for store value use: UserDefaults.standard.set(user.id, forKey: "userId" )
for load value use: let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")